# JQuery: Changing Height Based on Another Element

Tags: jquery, css

I have two DIVs: One DIV dynamically changes size based on the browser (responsive design) and I want the other DIV to modify its height based on the first DIV's height. I thought the easiest way to do this would be to use JQuery to dynamically change the height.

I tried the following:

```
$('section#div2').css({height:$(this).css('height').replace($('section#div1 div.div1_container').height()+'px')});
```

However, that code isn't working. Nor are various other versions of that working.

My question is: How can I replace a single CSS property without changing all of the properties for a given element?

EDIT: This is how the dynamic first DIV is coded...

First the first DIV's container:

```
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 50%;
padding-top: 30px; height: 0; overflow: hidden;
margin:0 0.7em 0 0.7em;
```

Then, the inner object within that container (may not be relevant):

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('section#div2').css('height', $('section#div1').height()+'px');
```

Comment: I tried this and it still didn't work. I'm going to update the question with the dynamic code for the first div in case that has any impact... Basically, when I tried the code you listed, it was the same result, no change to the height when the page was loaded.

Comment: The html markup is actually a bit more important. I've updated the jQuery with what I think you're trying to do, basically you want the height of section#div2 to be the same as section#div1 correct?

Comment: Yes, but that still doesn't work. I think the problem may be the way in which the first DIV is coded, since the height is technically zero. But, I tried setting it equal to the inner DIV too (which is 100%) and it still doesn't work... Thanks for the ideas so far though!

Comment: Ok, I added another inner DIV set to 100% width and height and it worked! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
$('section#div2').height($('section#div1').height());
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this one... sorry!

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't reference the first DIV at all, so how would it get that height? I tried it and it didn't do anything. Did you mean to include this within my CSS selector above somewhere?

Comment: Thanks this one works, too! I already accepted the first answer though that also works. I'll give you a vote up though for the answer - I appreciate the help!

Comment: As for which one is better, I was looking to update the CSS via the .css() selector rather than the .height() attribute directly. Although this answer is technically less lines of code.

Comment: @WillBuddha not to be contradictory, but if you look at the [jquery 1.7 source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js) on lines 6827 and 6670, internally, $.height() is calling the $.css() methods.